# How to git clone an OpenShift application to Android

Tags: android, git, ssh, openshift

I would like to make some changes in the source of my OpenShift web application on my Android tablet.

I am trouble with `git clone` because git client (eg. SGit) cannot recognize the given link by the OpenShift.

```
ssh://r4nd0mh4sh@myapp-me.rhcloud.com/~/.git/myapp.git/
```

Has anyone experience how to clone a repo like this with a normal git client? Is there any workaround to solve this, or just a "better" app which eats this link correctly?

I know Linux can easily installed as second os, and also using an ssh clien it is possible to edit the source directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully cloned all my Openshift repositories via SSH using SGit. Follow these steps:

1. Import your private key in SGit (Main page > Menu > Private Keys)
2. Provide your corresponding public key in your Openshift account
3. Add a new repository in SGit

   - Provide the Openshift SSH url as "Remote URL"
   - Choose a individual "Local Path"
   - Leave "Username" and "Password" empty
   - Press "Clone"

Comment: [How to generate SSH keys on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73555/how-can-i-create-a-key-par-for-sgit) shortcut for the future